# Пошаговое выполнение алгоритма, с показом текущего результата

Tags: алгоритм, многопоточность, потоки-данных, qt, c++

Интересует такое вопрос.

Как лучше реализовать пошаговое выполнение алгоритма в своей программе, среда Qt C++. Есть алгоритм работу которого нужно приостановить в обозначенных местах, после остановки пользователю  в главное окно должны быть показаны некоторые данные (по процессу выполнения алгоритма), на главной форме кнопка по нажатию которой алгоритм продолжает работу до следующей точки остановки и снова показ результатов. Алгоритм будет достаточно громоздкий содержать несколько классов.

Есть некоторые соображения выполнение алгоритма запустить в другом потоке, и в нужных местах ставить поток на паузу, а кнопкой на форме восстанавливать, только проблема в том что в Qt нет возможности поставить поток на паузу, если в Windows это и можно как то реализовать, то в Linux я вообще не вижу решения.

Жду вашего совета. Может есть проверенные способы решить поставленную проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача очень типичная и решение для нее известное. Основной класс, который Вам нужен - [QWaitCondition](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qwaitcondition.html). У этого класса есть метод wait, который формально ставит поток на паузу. (поток должен поставить себя на паузу самостоятельно). Когда поток нужно разбудить (снять с паузы), используются методы wakeOne/wakeAll (дело в том, что на паузе могут ждать несколько потоков, а wakeAll их всех разбудит). Главное, что нужно понимать, что этому классу нужен мютекс, который он будет использовать для своей работы (такая специфика).

И второе, после того, как поток разбудили (то есть метод wait завершил работу), нужно проверять условие "выхода из ожидания". Методы wait + wake так проектируются, что иногда wait "может проснуться случайно". Поэтому, обычно ожидание выглядит так

```
while (is_pause) {
   wait();
}
```